# Excel 2013 Share External Data Access DB with Clients

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a Excel 2013 workbook with a external data connection to an access 2013 db. Is there any way to email my Excel workbook and keep the data connection working? Right now when I email the workbook I am copy/pasting it into a worksheet, but it is growing fast. I dont think this is going to work in a few weeks. Also the person I am emailing doesnt have access. I am pretty much thinking I need to change it over to a mssql server or something, I am just not very familiar with the products.

What do you think is the best way to share this excel workbook and keep a link to a db?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks alot

Comment: Are they on the same network as you? Do they need to actively refresh the data or is the last snapshot you saw good enough?

Comment: They are not on the same network. Lately, I have just been emailing the workbook. The last snapshot I see is good enough. Thanks for your help.